# Using large IF ELSE string comparison to call different methods. More efficient method?

Tags: java, ajax, string, servlets, comparison

I'm using `JQuery` to call a `Java Servlet` from multiple places to call multiple different methods within the servlet. At the moment, I pass a string (called methodName) and then using an ever increasing IF ELSE block to see which function to call:

```
public String methodCaller(String methodName) throws SQLException, IOException
{
    if(methodName.equals("method1"))
    {
        return method1(attr("permit"));
    }
    else if(methodName.equals("method2"))
    {
        return method2(attr("ring"));
    }
    else if(methodName.equals("method3"))
    {
        return method3(attr("gridRef"));
    }
    else if(methodName.equals("method4"))
    {
        return method4(attr("ring"));
    }
    else if(methodName.equals("method6"))
    {
        return method6(attr("ring"), Integer.parseInt(attr("quantity")));
    }
```

However, this seems awfully clunky and inefficient to me, especially as the amount of methods will increase in future. Is there a more efficient way to compare the strings? Or should I simply make a separate servlet for each method (and simply do the processing in the `processRequest`?

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: java 7 allows switch for strings. This is not more efficient, but is more pleasant for eyes.

Comment: if you want to spend some time, this looks like a good place to utilize reflection. a `Map<String, Method>` could work nicely here. you can populate the map by creating an annotation and iterating through annotated methods, placing them in the map as needed. then you can use the `invoke()` method in the `Method` class to call whatever method you've decided needs to be called. it's a bit of work, but it's very clean and extensible once you've got it setup.

Comment: We're using Java 6.
Thanks @AlexLynch, I've heard of reflection, and will likely look into it, but probably won't be able to use it in this instance because of other factors affecting what technologies can be used and what can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend making each one of your methods an object that implements a simple interface.  In your class, create a HashMap linking each implementation of the interface to its respective key.

**Interface**

```
public interface MyMethod {
   public String call();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
   public class MethodOne implements MyMethod{

   }
```

**Mapping & Call**

```
    private Map<String, MyMethod> mappings = new HashMap<String,MyMethod>();

    static{
        mappings.put("method1", new MethodOne());
        //.. other mappings
    }

   public String methodCaller(String methodName) throws SQLException, IOException
   {
      MyMethod myMethod = mappings.get(methodName);
      return myMethod.call();
   }
```

Comment: I like this idea, thanks. I presume they'd be no issues with passing parameters to the call method via the methodCaller, and it would work as usual?

Comment: @Spam there wouldn't be any issues, but I wouldn't pass them if they were basically String literals.  If your going to pass String literals I would just place them in the class instead.

Comment: @SpAm Just as a follow up, this design loosely follows the open closed principle.  The static mappings violate the principle, but as I said "loosely" follows.

Comment: Well it's working well for me at the moment. I will likely adapt it later to be more fitting with best practices if it's possible, but at the moment, it's made my code a lot neater, and dynamic, so thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend, you should consider restful webservice.. REST defines a set of architectural principles by which you can design Web services that focus on a system's resources, including how resource states are addressed and transferred over HTTP by a wide range of clients written in different languages.

There are many open source which helps you to implement restful servlet very easily... One of them is Apache Wink http://incubator.apache.org/wink/

There is good article on the same in IBM Developerworks

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-apachewink1/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-apachewink2/index.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-apachewink3/index.html

Other alternatives :

Spring MVC

Apache CXF http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html

Comment: Thanks, that may be a bit overkill for this particular situation. I shall definitely look into it though, as the application could grow considerably, and it may be the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply start using an integer.

in your javascript have a function like this

```
function convertmethod(methodname)
    {
    thereturn = -1;
    switch(methodname) {
        case "Method1" : thereturn = 1;break;
        case "Method2" : thereturn = 2;break;
        case "Method3" : thereturn = 3;break;
        case "Method4" : thereturn = 4;break;
        }
    return thereturn;
    }
```

Then in your java code you can also use a switch

```
public String methodCaller(int methodName) throws SQLException, IOException
    {
    switch(methodName) 
        {
        case 1: return method1(attr("permit"));break;
        case 2: return method2(attr("permit"));break;
        case 3: return method3(attr("ring"));break;
        case 4: return method4(attr("gridRed"));break;
        }

    }
```